# Struts 2 Junit Test case execution failed (StrutsTestCase.getActionProxy:138 » NullPointer)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, struts2

I created a sample struts 2 project & junit test case by referring the below link.

http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com.au/2015/04/struts2-junit-integration.html

But, while executing the test case I am getting following error,

**Error in Eclipse JUNIT stacktrace**

[image: eclipse resolution]

Can Anyone advice me how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I have posted the answer for resolving the issue in eclipse. But getting a new error in maven build test execution. I will post that as a new question.

Comment: Now that the linked question is resolved. Would suggest sharing the code for `TestNumberAction.testGetNthPrime` and relevant code that it is testing.  Please update the question with minimal, verifiable info such that who reads can try and reproduce as well ensuring http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @nullpointer: Thanks. I will follow the practice(minimal & verifiable) in future posts. After resolving that issue, I am facing this error again in maven build. Can anyone advice how to resolve this issue in maven test case execution. It was working fine in eclipse after adding the classes folder in build path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in eclipse is resolved after adding the classes folder in the build path.

[image: Eclipse Error]

But after I faced a new [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015488/junit-maven-build-error-maven-surefire-plugin2-19-1test-failed-there-was-an) during maven build test execution.