# Junit maven build error (maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, struts2

I created a sample struts 2 project & J-unit test case by referring the  [link](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com.au/2015/04/struts2-junit-integration.html).

**Below is my POM file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>au.com.woolworths</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts_junit</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>struts_junit Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
       <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.3.4</version>
      </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
       <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.3.4</version>
      </dependency>
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>struts_junit</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
        <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
             <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                        <groupId>
                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                        </groupId>
                        <artifactId>
                            maven-toolchains-plugin
                        </artifactId>
                        <versionRange>
                            [1.1,)
                        </versionRange>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>toolchain</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <action>
                        <ignore></ignore>
                    </action>
                </pluginExecution>
            </pluginExecutions>
          </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
              <parallel>methods</parallel>
              <threadCount>10</threadCount>
              <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I am able to execute the test-case successfully in eclipse, but during maven build, I am getting the below error.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.768 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-03T11:22:46+11:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/168M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project struts_junit: Execution default-test of goal org.apach
e.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
[ERROR] at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
[ERROR] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.getConstructor(ReflectionUtils.java:79)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateOneArg(ReflectionUtils.java:130)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.createProviderInCurrentClassloader(ForkedBooter.java:321)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[ERROR] ... 22 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Can someone advice me why this error occurs and how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating your dependency should solve this -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

As mentioned in the [Javadoc for RunListener](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html), the class was introduced in version `4.0`. Also, do make sure the same artifact is not resolved with different version transitively.

Comment: @nillpointer, Thanks for addressing the issue. But Now I am facing another Issue after updating the dependency.

`<<< FAILURE! - in junit.tests.TestNumberAction
testGetNthPrime(junit.tests.TestNumberAction)  Time elapsed: 1.202 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at junit.tests.TestNumberAction.testGetNthPrime(TestNumberAction.java:12)
Results :
Tests in error:
  TestNumberAction.testGetNthPrime:12->StrutsTestCase.getActionProxy:138 » NullPointer`

Comment: that seems to be a test failure, you can ask that in a separate thread. Though prior to that I would suggest you to go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: i have already faced this issue in another project and posted in stackoverflow. Can you please .check this link as well ?  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014478/struts-2-junit-test-case-execution-failed-strutstestcase-getactionproxy138-n

Comment: I posted the answer for resolving the issue in eclipse(by adding the classes folder to project build path). But do not know how to resolve the same issue in maven build execution.